QGIS SAGA Isochrone crashes
I am trying to make isochrones with SAGA GIS.
I am now having a problem that:
The Isochrone variable speed crashes or give odd outputs.
I have a DEM with 3.6km2, but the output is about 3 pixels,
even though the flow accumulation and slope shows quite reliable values.
I put my filled DEM, slope, and flow accumulation.
What I am expecting to be the problem is:

I didn't specify spatial references
The target point is not the outlet point and something else
I have a very wrong data (but I filled sinks, and resampled the grid)
I did wrong settings on the options (I'm not sure about what the threshold values mean...)

Also when I chose the interactive isochrome option, the program does not respond when I clicked on any place on the map with the black arrow. I am not sure why this happens, whether it's because of my computer spec or the program crash.
I am not much familiar with GIS tools.

